# Equivalent definitions of a sequential space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space.  In the [Wikipedia page for "Sequential Space"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space), it is claimed (without proof or specific reference) that the following two conditions are equivalent (definitions below):

1. Every sequentially closed set is closed.
2. For every topological space $Y$, every sequentially continuous map $f : X \to Y$ is continuous.

It's pretty easy to show that 1 implies 2.  **How can we prove that 2 implies 1?**

One approach might be to establish a "sequential Tietze extension theorem": given a sequentially closed set $E$ and a point $x \notin E$, let $f(E) = 0$ and $f(x) = 1$ and try to construct a sequentially continuous extension of $f$ to $X$.  This seems difficult and also might require additional assumptions on the space $X$, so maybe there is a better way.

Relevant definitions:

A subset $E \subset X$ is **sequentially closed** if for every sequence $\{x_n\} \subset E$, if $x_n \to x$ then $x \in E$.

A function $f : X \to Y$ is **sequentially continuous** if for every sequence $\{x_n\} \subset X$, if $x_n \to x$ then $f(x_n) \to f(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given any topological space $X$, the collection of sequentially open subsets of $X$ is a topology.  If you let $Y$ have the same underlying set as $X$ but have this new topology, then the identity $X\to Y$ is sequentially continuous, and is continuous iff every sequentially closed subset of $X$ is closed.